# executable jar file does not show text or panel when opened

Tags: java, jar, jinternalframe

I don't know why but when I export my project into an executable jar file, there are somethings that don't turn out as if you would run the program from eclipse. One frame doesn't open up, which just contains text in it. I have another internal frame which is a split pane and contains questions on the right hand side and information on the left hand side panel. But in the executable jar file it doesn't show the information on the left hand side. I don't know why this is happening, I also have tried many options when exporting the project (making a jar file) but nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code for the frame that doesn't open up:

```
public class About implements ActionListener, InternalFrameListener{

private int openFrameCount;
private JDesktopPane desk;
private JTextArea Tarea;
private JScrollPane scroll;
private BufferedReader in ;
private MyInternalFrame frame;

public About(JDesktopPane desktop) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    desk = desktop;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(frame == null || frame.getParent() == null && !frame.isIconifiable()){
    frame = new MyInternalFrame("SAD Imaging");
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("SADInfo.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    String line;
    String file = ""; 
    try {
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            file += line;
            file +="\n";

        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Tarea = new JTextArea();
    //System.out.println(file);

    Tarea.setText(file);
    Font f = new Font("TimesNewRoman", Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 16);
    Tarea.setFont(f);
    Tarea.setBackground(Color.white);
    Tarea.setAlignmentX(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    Tarea.setEditable(false);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(Tarea);
    panel.setBackground(Color.white);

     //scroll = new JScrollPane(Tarea);
     scroll = new JScrollPane(panel,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

     //open the frame in the middle of the desktop. 
        Dimension desktopSize = desk.getSize();
        Dimension jInternalFrameSize = frame.getSize();
        frame.setLocation((desktopSize.width - jInternalFrameSize.width)/2, (desktopSize.height- jInternalFrameSize.height)/2);

    frame.add(scroll);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    desk.add(frame);

     try {
            frame.setSelected(true);
    } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {

    }
     frame.addInternalFrameListener(this);

    }

    else {
        try {
            //frame.setIcon(true);
            frame.setMaximizable(true);
            frame.setIconifiable(false);
            frame.setSelected(true);
            frame.moveToFront();
            frame.toFront();
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {

    static final int xPosition = 30, yPosition = 30;
    public MyInternalFrame(String title) {
        super(title, true,true, true, true);
        setSize(600,500);

        // Set the window's location.
        setLocation(xPosition * openFrameCount, yPosition * openFrameCount);
    }
}
```

This file just contains text information.

Same problem with the split pane. Here is the code for it.

```
public class FrequentQuestions implements ActionListener, InternalFrameListener{

private int openFrameCount;
private JDesktopPane desk;
private JTextArea Tarea;
private JScrollPane scroll;
private BufferedReader in ;
JPanel panelQuestions = new JPanel();
JPanel panelAnswers = new JPanel();
JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
JTextPane tPane = new JTextPane();
String file ="";
//private FrequentQuestions quest;
JSplitPane pane ;
MyInternalFrame frame;


public FrequentQuestions(JDesktopPane desktop) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    desk = desktop;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(frame == null || frame.getParent() == null){
    frame = new MyInternalFrame("Frequently Asked Questions");

    String [] options = {"How to open/save images", "What formats can SAD Imaging open", "How to show information about an image",
            "Compute FFT/Inverse", "Graphs"};
    JList list = new JList(options);
    //list.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    //panelQuestions.add(list);
    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false)
                return;

            JList list = (JList) e.getSource();


            if (list.isSelectionEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("list selection is empty!");
            }

                int index = ((JList)e.getSource()).getSelectedIndex();
                if(index == 0){
                    //panelAnswers.removeAll();
                    file = "";
                    try {
                        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("openSave.txt"));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String line;

                    try {
                        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            System.out.println(line);
                            file += line;
                            file +="\n";

                        }
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    tPane.setText(file);
                    System.out.println("I am outputting!");
                }
                else if(index == 1){
                    //panelAnswers.removeAll();
                    file = "";
                    try {
                        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("format.txt"));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String line;
                    //String file = ""; 
                    try {
                        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            System.out.println(line);
                            file += line;
                            file +="\n";

                        }
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    tPane.setText(file);
                    System.out.println("2nd item selected");

                }
                else{
                    //panelAnswers.removeAll();
                    file = "";
                    try {
                        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("showInfo.txt"));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String line;

                    try {
                        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            System.out.println(line);
                            file += line;
                            file +="\n";

                        }
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    tPane.setText(file);
                    System.out.println("3rd item selected");
                }

        }

    });

    JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(list,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scroll = new JScrollPane(tPane,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    pane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, scroll1, scroll);
    pane.setAutoscrolls(true);
    pane.setOpaque(true);

    panelQuestions.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(259,50));
    panelQuestions.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    panelAnswers.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,30));
    pane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
    pane.setDividerLocation(290);
    scroll1.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    //Border border = new Border();
    //scroll1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    //open the frame in the middle of the desktop. 
    Dimension desktopSize = desk.getSize();
    Dimension jInternalFrameSize = frame.getSize();
    frame.setLocation((desktopSize.width - jInternalFrameSize.width)/2, (desktopSize.height- jInternalFrameSize.height)/2);

    frame.add(pane);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    desk.add(frame);

     try {
            frame.setSelected(true);
    } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e1) {

    }
    }
    else{
        try {
            //frame.setIcon(true);
            //frame.setMaximizable(true);

            frame.setSelected(true);
            frame.moveToFront();
            //frame.toFront();
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

private class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {

    static final int xPosition = 30, yPosition = 30;
    public MyInternalFrame(String title) {
        super(title, true,true, true, true);
        setSize(800,500);

        // Set the window's location.
        setLocation(xPosition * openFrameCount, yPosition * openFrameCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try running it from the command line to see if there are any errors or exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to load the file from the filesystem. Instead, you need to load it via a classloader.

[Getting Resources from a jar: classloader vs class resourceasstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559846/getting-resources-from-a-jar-classloader-vs-class-resourceasstream)

**Edit**: I'm assuming that the executable jar contains this text file. Is that the case?

Comment: yeah all the files are contained in the executable jar. Maybe I'll fix how it calls the files.

Comment: I'm kind of confused, my files .txt format so how do I convert that to .class because it takes .class correct? I'm kind of confused on how to fix my code.

Comment: Thanks I understood it now. Basically I just had to do this: getClass().getResourceAsStream("openSave.txt"); Thank you again!!!!